# Efficient irreversible "serialization"?

Tags: hashing, serialization

Suppose we have a function `f` that gets a complex (non-flat) object as an input, serializes it, calculates hash of serialization results (e.g. md5) and returns calculated hash.

It may use some exiting serialization method, e.g. msgpack.

But are there any known techniques that may be more efficient than full (reversible) serialization and preserve `f`'s properties as a hashing function (e.g., collision probability)?

Comment: Efficient in what sense? Serializing and hashing is a linear time operation. You can only squeeze a constant factor improvement out of any hashing method. But if you have a specialized use case such as repeatedly serializing different object graphs that overlap, you can do much better.

Comment: Well, efficient in a practical sense, i.e. in sense of cpu and memory usage. For example, more efficient (hypothetical) implementation may require reduced intermediate buffer size (if we don't need to keep full serialization results) of reduced number of allocations (e.g. if we were able to use a circular buffer instead of dynamically growing buffer for serialization results).

Comment: If you can serialize to a stream and you can hash from a stream then you can pipeline serialization to the hasher to use very little memory. If your language allows direct memory access then you can hash the memory containing the object directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the notion of [composable hash functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0029r0.html).

The idea is that you have some snippets and you want to do some of the hashing for each snippet and the combine the hash results.  So, some hashing API's are designed to allow you to start the hash, then add more into the hash, then finish.  This is useful in a number of situations, for one, when you have several snippets instead of a (serialized) whole to hash.  For another, when the snippets each have their own different preferred mechanism for hashing.

Comment: Interesting. What is the correct term for this technique? Incremental hashing?

Comment: It seems that "incremental hashing" is [another thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324725/what-does-it-mean-for-a-hash-function-to-be-incremental), however this term is sometimes used for this technique too.

Comment: E.g. [here](https://github.com/jandrewrogers/MetroHash) or [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/Yawning/poly1305).